# clipping a vector layer with another vector layer using python

Tags: python, clip

Sorry if this there is a really obvious solution to this question. I did not have any luck googling and looking at different books.

I have an OSM vector layer that I want to clip with another vector layer for the boundary of a city. Now I can do this easy enough in QGIS, but I wanted to do this in python since I have a collection of images to process and clip.

I imagined that clipping is such a common operation, that there must be clip functions in the major geospatial packages, but I have not been able to find anything like that so far. I was kinda surprised, or was wondering if I was looking under the wrong headings, terminology?

There are a few posts on this topic listed below.

[Clipping raster with vector layer using GDAL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16657/clipping-raster-with-vector-layer-using-gdal)

[Clipping shapefile with Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297268/clipping-shapefile-with-python)

["Clip" hole into Shapefile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216439/clip-hole-into-shapefile/302015#302015)

Now the first post is about 7 years old, and the later ones are a couple of years old.

Is the best way to do this to use something like `geopandas` and to then keep all geometries that intersect with the city polygon? But then how do I crop OSM polygons that are not completely contained within the city polygon boundary. I would like to keep partial polygons.

Is the code in the links above still valid, or are there better ways to do this now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Geopandas has recently introduced [the clip function](https://geopandas.org/reference/geopandas.clip.html). The syntax is:

```
clipped = geopandas.clip(data_source, mask)
```

Notes:

- `data_source` and `mask` must be in the same CRS.
- for MultiPoint, MultiLine, or MultiPolygon datasets, you first need to explode them into individual features using `gpd.explode()`

You can refer to [this tutorial](https://www.earthdatascience.org/courses/use-data-open-source-python/intro-vector-data-python/vector-data-processing/clip-vector-data-in-python-geopandas-shapely/) and to [the docs](https://geopandas.org/gallery/plot_clip.html) for examples and more info.

Answer (score 3):

it is indeed weird that there is nothing like that implemented in Geopandas or shapely. I got the same problem that I wanted to crop images that overlap with the boundary polygon.

This code does what you are looking for:

```
os.system("ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -clipsrc boundary.geojson datatobeclipped.geojson")
```

Comment: Oh thanks for the insight. Yeah, seems like there would be a smoother way to do this than resorting to passing to the shell, but this is great for now. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to specify a `dst_datasource_name` too, @Leo ?